# JPA and Mysql - Multiple Client Connections but just one User Account

Tags: mysql, jpa, parallel-processing

There is a central database and many clients which access it parallel per JPA. The clients have a permanent connection to the database. State synchronisation is only achieved by the database. The clients just update their views and blindly write back some input per JPA.

Is there a possibility not to have separate database user accounts per client? I would like to use just one user for all running clients.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but that is the normal configuration.

If you use a connection pool, or a DataSource it will have a single user id defined to connect with, and you will have a pool of those connections.